# why does spring data jpa map a one to one association to a one to many

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

i have 2 entities, Student and User. I'm using JPA to create a one to one relationship between them as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String specialty;
    private String level;
    private String type;
    private String institution;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String birthDate;
    private String adress;
    private int phone;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String type;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Student student;


}
```

this does create the relationship, however when i go to Mysql to see the tables the relationship is one to many, not one to one.

Comment: How are you determining that there is a OneToMany relationship here exactly? The PrimaryJoinColumn in User is just wrong, as you don't have a foreign key to associate with the primary key (the relationship is marked as mapped by user). Removing this would tell JPA that both tables only have an ID that must be unique, with the Student.ID being a foreign key to User.Id - a One To One.

Comment: i can tell because you can look up the schema in Mysql. and @PrimaryKeyKeyColumn is to my understanding needed to make the association based on the primary key

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. It is used more commonly in JPA 1.0 before there were derived IDs, where it was mostly aimed at having a way of specifying how to map multiple tables in the same entity (inheritance etc) and got reused on reference mappings. You might have used it on the Student.user mapping instead of MapsId so that JPA would know the foreign key in the mapping is tied to the id property - but JPA would NOT set the id property for you. It would behave as if you set a joinColumn and specified the same ID column and marked it updatable=false, insertable=false.

Comment: The @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn shouldn't be used in the User side because you've already told JPA that the mapping is controlled through the Student.user mapping. Adding it just confuses things, effectively stating that both IDs are fks to the other's ID. As for what you see in the schema ... what do you see in the schema compared to what you expect to see? There isn't much difference from a ManyToOne and OneToOne without adding a uniqueness constraint on the FK, and from the other side you won't see a fk at all.

Comment: ahh got it. as to what i expect to see, i expect to see a one to one relatioship, as that's what i define, so what caused the association to be mapped to one to many

Comment: You are not defining what you see, and there is no table structure difference between a bidirectional OneToOne compared to a ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship. One table will have a foreign key to the other. The only functional difference that prevents a Bidirectional one to one from 'being' a OneToMany is that you might have a uniqueness constraint placed on the foreign key - ensuring only one child can reference the parent instead of many. You don't need and won't see that here because your foreign key is the ID for the child, so it must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried exactly your code in Hibernate 6.2, and this was the generated DDL:

```sql
    create table Student (
        id bigint not null,
        institution varchar(255),
        level varchar(255),
        specialty varchar(255),
        type varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB

    create table User (
        id bigint not null,
        adress varchar(255),
        birthDate varchar(255),
        email varchar(255),
        firstName varchar(255),
        gender varchar(255),
        lastName varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        phone integer not null,
        type varchar(255),
        username varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB

    alter table Student 
       add constraint FKkfqq4nickg8wu56axc7jktv1 
       foreign key (id) 
       references User (id)
```

Looks like a pretty good one-to-one association to me.

### UPDATE

Note that I would map your association as follows, assuming that every `Student` has a `User`:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Student")
    public static class Student {
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne(optional=false)
        @MapsId 
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private User user;
        ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")
    public static class User {
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
        private Student student;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The code works. It's when you check it the data base schema In mysql the relationship is one to many, not one to one. Also why did u not add @primarykeyjoincolumn?

Comment: I understand all that. I'm saying that I _do_ get  a relationship based on the primary key. Look at the DDL I  posted! Hibernate generated that. That is a one-to-one association.

Comment: (And I did not add `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` because it's not needed.)

Comment: yeah im seeing the console, i got the same results as you, it's just weird how it goes to one to many in Mysql, and why is @PrimaryKeyColumn not needed?